# Inserting a aggregated colum into another column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I created a new column that I want to store just the year of the order date.
However I don't know how I insert the data from Orderdate column into the column just for the year

I tried Select INTO and Insert INTO but i believe they're could be an issue with my synta

I have tried this code so far but keep recieivng errors

```
INSERT INTO EuropeSales(YearOfSale)
Values (SELECT Year([Order Date]) FROM EuropeSales)
```

Comment: Do you really need different tables for each continent? Why not one, global Sales table?

Comment: Why are you trying to store the year when you can always do e.g. `WHERE YEAR([Order Date]) = 2019`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a `select` statement inside the `values` clause unless it returns only a single scalar value - but you can use `insert...select`:

```
INSERT INTO EuropeSales(YearOfSale)
SELECT Year([Order Date]) 
FROM EuropeSales
```

However, I think you are not looking for `insert` at all, but for `update`:

```
UPDATE EuropeSales
SET YearOfSale = Year([Order Date])
```

And having said that, It's usually not considered a wise choice to store values that can easily be calculated from other stored values.
See, now you have to maintain both the `Order Date` and the `YearOfSale` column - they depend on each other.

You can simply add `Year([Order Date]) as YearOfSale` to a select clause, or add that column as a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE EuropeSales
    ADD YearOfSale AS Year([Order Date]) PERSISTED
```

BTW, `Year` is not an aggregating function.
An aggregating function is a function that works on groups of values - such as `sum`, `count` etc'.

Comment: Reference [Table Value Constructor - Limitations and Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#limitations-and-restrictions): "Only single scalar values are allowed as a row value expression. A subquery that involves multiple columns is not allowed as a row value expression." A `select` that returns a single value is valid within a `values` clause: `select * from ( values ( -1 ), ( ( select 42 ) ), ( ( select Month( Getdate() ) ) ), ( ( select Max( Object_Id ) from sys.objects ) ) ) T( C );`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it!  SQL Server supports computed columns.  So, you can add the column *with the computation*.  It is always up-to-date:

```
ALTER TABLE EuropeSales ADD YearOfSale AS (Year([Order Date]);
```

This is then computed *when you use it*.  That means it is always correct.

This also means that you don't have to update every row in the table, which can get expensive due to logging.